# Concatenate in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have the variables `$day1, $day2 etc.`. But I don't have an existing $day variable. In my Blade, I have a for-loop that displays these variables. How do I display them as such? The code I have right now is

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
   <td>{{ '$' . 'day' .$i }}</td>
@endfor
```

Right now, it's displaying as `$day1, $day2` as strings instead of displaying the value of the vars $day1, $day2 etc. How do I do this in my blade templates?

Comment: why  don't u put them in array?

Comment: @TsaiKoga I have tried putting them in an array however my for-loop I have in the question will break my code. I have another foreach loop that displays the employee's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
   <td>{{ ${'day'.$i} }}</td>
@endfor
```

more detail you can see [Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Much detailed. This is what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: you can also wrap you day data to array and loop access it too. depend on your choice.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the variables as array.

```
@foreach($day as $days)
```

{{$day}}
@endforeach

I think you make wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap them in `{}`:
`${"day" . $i}`

---

Update:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
   <td>{{ ${"day" . $i} }}</td>
@endfor
```

Comment: Did you mean ${{"day" . $i}}? It gives me the same output. It returns as a string

Comment: {{ ${"day" . $i} }}